# How to get Google refresh_token on multiple devices

Tags: google-oauth, google-authentication

I am creating a node based authentication server for Google that my apps can use to get access tokens for google data apis.

I am basing this off the server side flow as described here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps

I am at the point where I am trying to implement the refresh token logic for when a token expires. For this I obviously need the `refresh_token`. I get the refresh token no problem - the first time that I access the service but subsequent times I do not.

I plan to keep these tokens in local storage on the browser so it's generally not a problem - until I access the same service on my mobile or any additional device.

How do I get a refresh token on a second or third device?

Surely I don't have to revoke the tokens and sign in again each time I want to switch to a new device?

Thanks